# What would be more efficient: three select queries, or a single query with a join?

Tags: sql

I have three tables:

```
A_details    
B_details    
C_details
```

What would be more efficient: three select queries, or a single query with a join?

Comment: What is the structures of these tables? and how they are related?

Comment: need relationship in these tables for join

Comment: What output are you looking for?

Comment: Without any information on the structure and relationships between these tables this question is meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will greatly depend on the schema, and if you have the correct indexes on the tables.

I typically prefer to let the database hadle joins, instead of trying to do it in code, the database is better at this.

The key here is if you have the correct indexes for the joins to read efficiently.

Have a look at [Database index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your database, but don't create JOINs when they don't make sense. You haven't specified any database or platform. If your platform allows multiple result sets per query, just issue the three SELECTs all at once, and get the three tables in one database request.

If your platform doesn't support it, access the database three times and don't try uniting your queries *unless you are sure this is a performance problem*.

Answer (score 0):

Joining tables is more efficient because normalization is a better approach.

Here I am using left outer joins for three tables joined on the common columns between the tables. So please replace column with col1, col2, col3... with what's appropriate for your tables, and refer to the query below:

```
select a.*, b.*, c.*
from A_details a 
left outer join B_details b on a.col1=b.col2
left outer join C_details c on a.col1=b.col3
```

---

For more details, please refer to:
    http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: please, give me your problem in details